# Does the following code/design have a concurrency issue

Tags: c#, concurrency

I have implemented a simple cache using the dictionary class:

```
private Dictionary<int, byte[]> cache = new Dictionary<int, byte>();

public void SetPicture(int id, byte[] bytes)
{
    cache[id] = bytes;
}

public byte[] GetPicture(int id)
{
    if (cache.Contains(id)) {
        return cache[id];
    }
    return null;
}
```

SetPicture is only called from a single background thread. (This background thread is updating user profile pictures from an active directory query).

GetPicture is called from multiple other threads (threads handling http requests).

**Items will never be removed from the cache.**

So is this code thread safe? Or do I need to block access to the internal Dictionary while writing to it in SetPicture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not safe; all access to a dictionary needs to be synchronized, as the contents of a `Dictionary<,>` are *not* guaranteed for readers against a writer. Also, a separate contains/get check is an obvious thread-race.

Options:

- use a 1.1-style `Hashtable` - that supports one writer **and** multiple concurrent readers **without**  synchronization (downside here is that your key, `int`, is a value-type, so will need to be boxed; `Hashtable` is more inviting when using a reference-type key, such as `string`)
- use a `ConcurrentDictionary<,>`
- use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` to synchronize (assuming reads are much more common than writes)
- use `lock` to synchronize (assuming non-trivial writes)

However! If you use the `Hashtable` approach **do not** do a separate `Contains` / get - just use the indexer. If you get `null` it wasn't there. Otherwise you have a race condition.

Comment: ReaderWriterLockSlim looks interesting - reads are common, writes are (probably) going to be rare.

Comment: With regards to the 'contains / get' race conditions - is this really a problem in my case? Because we will never remove items from the cache (I do not offer this in the public interface).

Comment: @GarethOwen in that case you're probably OK - but `TryGetValue` is more efficient **anyway** - you might as well call that instead

Comment: I added the line 'Items will never be removed from the cache' to the question - perhaps that was not clear enough from the initial post. I think this is crucial in order to design the most efficient and safe implementation.

Comment: @GarethOwen well, maybe; but since the initial design is already broken.... ;p Seriously, though, I would just use `TryGetValue` - one walk of the tree instead of 2

Comment: yes, thanks for the tip with TryGetValue - I didn't know about that

Answer (score 2):

Not thread safe. Use ConcurrentDictionary. Also GetPicture must return something if the entry cannot be found.

Comment: thanks for noticing the mistake in GetPicture - I updated the code in the question.